# How do I Programmatically invoke Argo by submitting an appropriate .YAML file

Tags: java, kotlin, kubernetes, yaml, argo-workflows

The only way I see so far to create a container using Argo is through the command line:

`argo submit --watch fileName.yaml`

I would like to invoke Argo programmatically in Kotlin or Java in order to automate this process. Is there a way I can do that?

I've looked into documentation on Github: https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows. I did not find anything there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I accomplished this task by invoking the Kubernetes API. Argo is a Custom Resource of Kubernetes, and has equivalent Kubernetes command

`kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/master/examples/hello-world.yaml`

I just had to invoke the above command using the Kubernetes API.

Answer (score 1):

Next release v2.5 will support GRPC API call support all Argo workflow operations. you can programmatically do all workflow related operations. Even you can generate SDK also.